# What is the distribution of $W$?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $W=\int_0^t B_sds$. Find $EW$ and $EW^2$. What is the distribution of $W$?

From the definition, we have
$$
EW=\int_0^t EB_sds=0
$$
and
$$
EW^2=\int_0^t EB^2_sds=\int_0^t sds=t^2/2.
$$

But how to describe the distribution of $W$? Does it sound like $W\sim N(0, t^2/2)$?

Comment: $\mathbb E[W^2] \neq \int_0^t \mathbb E[B_s^2]ds$. Moreover, the equality $\mathbb E[W] = \int_0^t \mathbb E[B_s]ds$ isn't a definition, but a fact which follows from Fubinii's theorem and finiteness of $\int_0^t \mathbb E|B_s|ds$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $n\ge 1$, let $\Delta s:=t/n$ and for $k=0,\ldots, n-1$ let $s_k:=k\Delta s$. Consider the Riemann sum approximation of $W$:
$$
W^{(n)}=\Delta s\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}B(s_k).
$$
Since $W^{(n)}\to W$ as $n\to\infty$ and each $W^{(n)}$ is Gaussian, the limit is also Gaussian. Trivially, $\mathsf{E}W^{(n)}=0$, and  since $\operatorname{Cov}(B(s_k),B(s_j))=\min\{s_k,s_j\}$,
$$
\mathsf{E}\big(W^{(n)}\big)^2=\frac{t^2}{n^2}\left(\frac{tn^2}{3}-\frac{tn}{2}+\frac{t}{6}\right)\to \frac{t^3}{3}
$$
as $n\to\infty$. Thus, $W\sim N(0, t^3/3)$.